# No audio on startup until I pull the headphone plug out

Tags: linux-mint, audio

Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria

No audio on startup until I pull the headphone plug out and plug it back in. It also seems to happen when waking up from suspend mode (doesn't seem to happen every time, but I can be wrong).

`pavucontrol` is not installed, should it be?

The `pacmd list-sinks` doesn't explain anything to me, except the related `module-udev-detect.discovered = 1`.

But here is the interesting part:
On startup it says
`active port: <analog-output-headphones>`
and there is no sound in headphones.

After physical pluging in it changes to
`active port: <analog-output-lineout>`
and I have sound immediately.

It happened before with version before 20, but never with 20 (now I have 21.2).

Where should I go? What **direction?**

It's not so much disturbing, but it is not the right way for things to be happen.

---

FYI: built-in audio, old one and very common.

Audio:
Device-1: Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio vendor: Gigabyte GA-D525TUD
driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:27d8
Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-89-generic running: yes
Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

System:
Kernel: 5.15.0-89-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0 Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 wm: marco
dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: G31M-ES2L serial:  BIOS: Award v: FG
date: 02/24/2010
CPU:
Info: dual core model: Pentium E5300 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Core Yorkfield rev: A cache:
L1: 128 KiB L2: 2 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 2600 min/max: 1200/2600 cores: 1: 2600 2: 2600 bogomips: 10399
Flags: ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 vmx